# How can I map two separate json objects with key values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new to angularjs. In my json data there are two objects categories and sub_categories.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "categories": {
            "1": "Fasteners",
            "2": "Paints",
            "3": "Abrasives"
        },
        "sub_categories": {
            "1": [
                "Select All",
                "Nuts",
                "Bolts",
                "others"
            ],
            "2": [
                "All",
                "Industrial Paints",
                "Primer"
            ],
            "3": "3",
            "4": "4"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to map the sub_categories under respective categories. I can get the key values of categories and sub_categories by`ng-repeat="(keyCat,cat) in myData.data.categories "` and `ng-repeat = "(keySubCat,subCat) in myData.data.sub_categories"` respectively but I'm not able to find a way to map them.

Can anyone please give a possible solution or guide me how to map these two objects.

---

My 2nd question is how can I implement a search to this json objects. This is not a json array so I'm not be able to use filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keyCat` from the categories.

```
<div ng-repeat="(keyCat,cat) in myData.data.categories">
  {{cat}}
  <div ng-repeat="subCat in myData.data.sub_categories[keyCat]">
    {{subCat}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Although I would change the data structure to include the subcategories in the category value.

Comment: thanks , this is what I need. Can you give any hints on implementing search @taguenizy

Comment: On categories? I would add a `ng-if` with some function taking `cat` as an argument. `<div ng-repeat="(keyCat,cat) in myData.data.categories" ng-if="someSearchLogic(cat)">`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
var categories = Object.keys(data.categories).map(function(key) {
    var cat = {
    id: key,
      name: data.categories[key],
    sub_categories: data.sub_categories[key]
  }
  return cat;
});
```

Now that you transformed it into an array, you may search it easier.